# Looking for a way to remove c++ dynamic_cast (virtual functions, templates)

Tags: c++

I have created the following example to illustrate a design in an existing product.  I heard that using dynamic_cast should be minimized or removed.  I am looking to the community to see if there is an alternate/better way to design this.  Below is a simplified example of the program:

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Key
{
public:
    unsigned int num_teeth;
    Key(unsigned int t): num_teeth(t) {}
    virtual ~Key() {}
};

class MansionKey:
public Key
{
//mansion keys have chips with frequencies
public:
    unsigned int freq;
    MansionKey(unsigned int t, unsigned int f):
         Key(t), freq(f)  {}

    virtual ~MansionKey() {}
};

class House
{
public:
    void leaveHouse(vector<Key> *vp)  {_my_keys = vp;}   //take keys with you
    void comeBackHome()
    {
        vector<Key>::iterator    iter = _my_keys->begin();
        for (; iter != _my_keys->end(); ++iter)
        {
            if (unlockDoor(&*iter));
                break;
        }
    }
    virtual bool unlockDoor (Key * k)
    {   return k->num_teeth == door_lock_teeth;    }

    unsigned int door_lock_teeth;
    vector<Key> *_my_keys;
    House(){}
    virtual ~House() {}
};

class Mansion:
public House
{
public:
    unsigned int door_freq;
    virtual bool unlockDoor(Key *k)
    {
        MansionKey *mk = dynamic_cast<MansionKey *>(k);   //I know that this is a mansion key
        return ((door_lock_teeth == mk->num_teeth) &&
                (door_freq == mk->freq));
    }

    Mansion() {}
    virtual ~Mansion() {}
};

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    House *hp =0;
    vector<Key>    bagOKeys;
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        //Mansion mode
        Mansion *mp = new Mansion();
        mp->door_freq = 1024;
        mp->door_lock_teeth = 5;
        hp= mp;
        bagOKeys.push_back(MansionKey(3, 777));
        bagOKeys.push_back(MansionKey(5, 1024));
    }
    else
    {
        hp = new House();
        hp->door_lock_teeth = 7;
        bagOKeys.push_back(Key(3));
        bagOKeys.push_back(Key(7));
    }

    hp->leaveHouse(&bagOKeys);
    hp->comeBackHome();

    delete hp;
}
```

I suppose I could copy all the operations of MansionKey into Key, but that tends to break the illustration that not all keys are mansion keys or have mansion key properties.

I wish there were a way to have specialized template parameters to the virtual function, but the language doesn't allow that either.

What are some other ideas?

Comment: The program has a serious flaw in that you have a `vector<Key>` and you're placing `MansionKey`'s in it.  That is [*object slicing*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) and it isn't a good thing.

Comment: one of the options would be `template<typename KeyType=Key> House;` then `class Mansion: public House<MansionKey> unlockDoor(KeyType *k)` 

another - to use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern

Comment: fukanchik: would that allow me to use the `virtual void unlockDoor(KeyType *k)?`